# BinaryTree<T> written in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've written a binary-tree using `.NET Core 3.0`.  What can I do to improve my coding style?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace BinaryTree
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a binary tree <seealso href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type which this tree should contain.</typeparam>
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable, new()
    {
#if DEBUG
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether or not to log actions in the console.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool Log = true;
#endif

        [DataMember]
        private Node<T> _parentNode;

        public BinaryTree()
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (Log)
                Console.WriteLine("Initializing binary-tree..");
#endif
            _parentNode = new Node<T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the specific item inside the binary-tree using binary-tree logic.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">The item that will be added.</param>
        public void Add(T item)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (Log)
                Console.WriteLine("Initializing binary-tree..");
#endif
            _parentNode.Add(item);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the specific item inside the binary-tree using binary-tree logic. The root node cannot be removed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">The item that will be removed.</param>
        public void Remove(T item)
        {
            _parentNode.Remove(item);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Searches for a specific item inside this binary-tree using binary-tree logic.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        /// <returns>Returns the count of said item if existing - 0 if otherwise.</returns>
        public int Contains(T item)
        {
            return _parentNode.Contains(item);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears everything out of this binary-tree.
        /// </summary>
        public void Clear()
        {
            _parentNode = new Node<T>();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is BinaryTree<T> tree && tree._parentNode.Equals(_parentNode);
        }

        public void Serialize(string file)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, this);
            }
        }

        public static BinaryTree<T> Deserialize(string file)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                return (BinaryTree<T>)bf.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a node of a binary-tree. This may be either a simple node, a parent, or a leaf.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type which this node should contain.</typeparam>
        [Serializable]
        [DataContract]
        private class Node<T> where T : IComparable, new()
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Right "lower" arm of current node - this is where everything bigger than this node is getting redirect towards.
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember]
            private Node<T> _bigger;

            /// <summary>
            /// Saved data and count of data - inside this specific node.
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember]
            private (T data, int count) _item;

            /// <summary>
            /// Root node, if existing.
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember]
            private Node<T> _parent;

            /// <summary>
            /// Left "lower" arm of current node - this is where everything smaller than this node is getting redirect towards.
            /// </summary>
            [DataMember]
            private Node<T> _smaller;

            private Node(T item)
            {
                _item = (item, 1);
            }

            public Node()
            {
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                return obj is Node<T> node &&
                       (node._bigger?.Equals(_bigger) ?? _bigger == null) &&
                       (node._item.data?.Equals(_item.data) ?? _item.data == null) &&
                       (node._item.count.Equals(_item.count)) &&
                       (node._parent?.Equals(_parent) ?? _parent==null) &&
                       (node._smaller?.Equals(_smaller) ?? _smaller == null);
            }

            private void Set(T data)
            {
                if (_item.data.Equals(default(T)))
                {
                    _item = (data, 1);
                    return;
                }

                if (data.Equals(_item.data))
                    _item.count++;
                else
                    Add(data);
            }

            public void Remove(T data)
            {
                if (data.Equals(_item.data))
                {
                    if (_item.count > 1)
                    {
                        _item.count--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_parent == null) return;

                        var replacement = new Node<T>(data)
                        {
                            _smaller = _smaller,
                            _bigger = _bigger,
                            _parent = _parent
                        };

                        if (_parent._item.data.CompareTo(_item.data) == 1)
                            _parent._smaller = replacement;
                        else
                            _parent._bigger = replacement;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (data.CompareTo(_item.data) == 1)
                    {
                        _bigger?.Remove(data);
                        if (_bigger != null) _bigger._parent = this;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _smaller?.Remove(data);
                        if (_smaller != null) _smaller._parent = this;
                    }
                }
            }

            public void Add(T item)
            {
                if (_item.data.Equals(default(T)))
                {
                    Set(item);
                    return;
                }

                if (item.CompareTo(_item.data) == 1)
                {
#if DEBUG
                    if (Log)
                        Console.WriteLine($"{item} > {_item.data} → move to right lower node..");
#endif
                    (_bigger = CreateOrReturnNode(_bigger)).Set(item);
                }
                else
                {
#if DEBUG
                    if (Log)
                        Console.WriteLine($"{item} < {_item.data} → move to left lower node..");
#endif
                    (_smaller = CreateOrReturnNode(_smaller)).Set(item);
                }
            }

            public int Contains(T value)
            {
                if (_item.data.Equals(value))
                {
#if DEBUG
                    if (Log)
                        Console.WriteLine("Item was found!");
#endif
                    return _item.count;
                }

                if (value.CompareTo(_item.data).Equals(1))
                {
#if DEBUG
                    if (Log)
                        Console.WriteLine($"{value} > {_item.data} → search in right lower node..");
#endif
                    return _bigger?.Contains(value) ?? 0;
                }

#if DEBUG
                if (Log)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{value} < {_item.data} → search in left lower node..");
#endif
                return _smaller?.Contains(value) ?? 0;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Either creates a new node, or returns the existing one.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="node">The node which is getting checked whether it is set or not.</param>
            /// <returns>Either a new node, or the already existing one.</returns>
            private static Node<T> CreateOrReturnNode(Node<T> node = null)
            {
                return node ?? new Node<T>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated Version: https://github.com/TheRealVira/binary-tree/blob/master/BinaryTree/BinaryTree.cs**

Comment: Is this finished? `_parent` doesn't seem to be touched outside `Remove`, so it looks like you were half-way through a refactor to either add or remove the field.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I have added some comments and serialization options to it, but the _parent is as is "finished". It seemed like the easiest and quickest way to solve the removal process.

Comment: Please, please remove the #if DEBUG everywhere... consider having one method do your logging, marked with [ConditionalCompilation("DEBUG")], to achieve the same outcome without #if all over the place.

Comment: I have updated my code to the newest version.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ```
>     public class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable, new()
> ```

I suspect that you are unaware of the possibility of writing

```
    public class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>, new()
```

If you did deliberately choose `IComparable` over `IComparable<T>`, it would be helpful to add a comment explaining why.

Why `where T : new()`? The code doesn't call `new T()` anywhere.

The class would be a lot more powerful if you also implemented `IEnumerable<T>`, and ideally you would implement `ICollection<T>`.

---

> ```
>         private Node<T> _parentNode;
> ```

`Node` is an inner class, so it doesn't need the type parameter. You can remove it, and `T` from the outer class will be in scope. If you've come to C# from Java then note that this is one of the bigger differences in their type systems.

---

> ```
> #if DEBUG
>             if (Log)
>                 Console.WriteLine("Initializing binary-tree..");
> #endif
> ```

If you use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` then (a) you can skip all the `#if DEBUG`; (b) when running in Visual Studio the log will be available in the Output pane even after the process has finished.

Alternatively you could take it up a level and use a proper runtime-configurable logging library like Serilog, log4net, ...

---

> ```
>         public void Add(T item)
>         {
> #if DEBUG
>             if (Log)
>                 Console.WriteLine("Initializing binary-tree..");
> #endif
>             _parentNode.Add(item);
>         }
> ```

That log message looks suspicious...

Also, I see you've made a design decision to push the majority of the logic into the nodes. Since you appear to be doing this as a learning exercise, I suggest that for comparison you separately implement a version which leaves the nodes as pure data objects and puts all the logic in the methods of `BinaryTree`. That lets you use tail optimisation (turn recursion into a `while` loop).

---

> ```
>         public override bool Equals(object obj)
>         {
>             return obj is BinaryTree<T> tree && tree._parentNode.Equals(_parentNode);
>         }
> ```

Visual Studio gives me a warning about this: when you override `Equals` you should override `GetHashcode` because otherwise you will spend ages debugging if you ever put an instance of this class in a `HashSet<>` or as the key in a `Dictionary`.

The same applies to `Node`.

---

> ```
>             /// <summary>
>             /// Right "lower" arm of current node - this is where everything bigger than this node is getting redirect towards.
>             /// </summary>
>             [DataMember]
>             private Node<T> _bigger;
> ```

I managed to understand the code ok, but it would be more conventional to call this `_right`. (Or maybe `right`, but I don't want to be pedantic about that kind of naming convention).

---

> ```
>             private (T data, int count) _item;
> ```

That `count` is unusual. In effect you're implementing an `IDictionary<T, int>`: perhaps it would make sense to generalise to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and have a separate wrapper class which turns any `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` into a counter.

---

```
            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                return obj is Node<T> node &&
                       (node._bigger?.Equals(_bigger) ?? _bigger == null) &&
                       (node._item.data?.Equals(_item.data) ?? _item.data == null) &&
                       (node._item.count.Equals(_item.count)) &&
                       (node._parent?.Equals(_parent) ?? _parent==null) &&
                       (node._smaller?.Equals(_smaller) ?? _smaller == null);
            }
```

`ValueStruct` overrides `==`, so you could simplify this a bit. Unless you want to be paranoid and assume that `T` might not have `Equals` consistent with `CompareTo`, in which case you should use `CompareTo` here to compare `_item.data`.

---

> ```
>             public void Remove(T data)
>             {
>                 if (data.Equals(_item.data))
>                 {
>                     if (_item.count > 1)
>                     {
>                         _item.count--;
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         if (_parent == null) return;
> ```

The only place that `_parent` is touched is in `Remove`, so if I add one item to the tree and then call `Remove` with that same item, it won't be removed.

---

> ```
>             public int Contains(T value)
>             {
>                 if (_item.data.Equals(value))
> ```

I got a `NullReferenceException` here when I called `Contains` on an empty tree.

---

> ```
>             public void Add(T item)
>             {
>                 if (_item.data.Equals(default(T)))
> ```

I got a `NullReferenceException` here when the tree was empty: did you test this code at all?

---

> ```
>                         if (_parent._item.data.CompareTo(_item.data) == 1)
>                     if (data.CompareTo(_item.data) == 1)
>                 if (item.CompareTo(_item.data) == 1)
>                 if (value.CompareTo(_item.data).Equals(1))
> ```

The contract of `IComparable` does not say that the value returned will always be `-1`, `0`, or `1`. I'm not sure why lots of people seem to think that it does. You should always compare the return value against `0`.

Comment: So, as far as I understood your reply, in this scenario it would be better to check if a value is greater then 0? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Yes. The foolproof way of using `CompareTo` is to write the code without it: `if (_data > _item.data)`, then move the RHS to the argument of `CompareTo` and replace it with `0`: `if (_data.CompareTo(_item.data) > 0)`.

Comment: I need "where T :  IComparable, new()" for my Clear function. This is where I have to create a new node.

Comment: You create a `new Node<T>()`, but not a `new T()`.

Comment: I have updated my code and is now accessible on my github repo: https://github.com/TheRealVira/binary-tree/blob/master/BinaryTree/BinaryTree.cs

Comment: @TheRealVira, [it is permitted to post a new question with your revised code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/1402). However, before doing that I strongly advise you to write some unit tests. The "Remove doesn't remove" bug is still present, and it's very easy to write a unit test to catch it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would prefer not to have a private Node class inside the BinaryTree class.
I think that the logic for adding/removing nodes in the tree should be done at the Tree class and not at the Node class level.

Maybe move the Node class into its own file, rename it to BinaryNodeTree and move the add/remove logic to the tree itself, which can use a utility class for searching the node to add the value too.

Comment: This would probably also solve my _parent "problem". Thx!

Comment: Why pollute the namespace with a `BinaryNodeTree` class? The scope in which it will be used is inside the tree, so the class belongs inside the tree.

Comment: @PeterTaylor this may be since my teacher, a "java specialist", tried to teach me to do that and called it good practice.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Also this is why I have wanted to learn by myself lol

Comment: @TheRealVira, in case it's not clear, I'm disagreeing with Shai Aharoni. Moving the logic out of the node is probably a good idea, and I also suggested that, but in my opinion moving the `Node` class outside the `BinaryTree` class offers only disadvantages.